# Unknown blueprint: resource in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember-cli: 3.1.4. I want to create resource file. I have used "ember g resource data". But I cannot create it and the reply is like "Unknown blueprint: resource". Is resource is dropped in the latest version? or still is there? If it is dropped, is there any other methods to use the same feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `resource` blueprint has been removed (starting in 2.0). That blueprint generates both a model and a route.

You can achieve the same thing doing `ember generate model <name>` and `ember generate route <name>`.

You can also install https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-legacy-blueprints which includes the `resource` blueprint.